# How to print data in Django views.py not in template?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I know how to get the data from the database and send to the template. But i am in a situation where I need to print the data from the database in `views.py` file

```
order = Order.objects.get(user=request.user, ordered=False)
context['object']=order
return render(request,"Orderview.html",context)
```

this order variable contains title,quantity,price of the product

```
{% for order_item in object.items.all %}
                <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><strong>{{ order_item.item.title }}<</strong><br>{{order_item.item.description }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ order_item.quantity }}</td>
                <td class="text-right" id="price" >{{ order_item.item.price }}</td>
                <td class="text-right" id="discount ">{{ order_item.item.discount_price }}</td>
                <td class="text-right" id="subtotal_price">{{ order_item.item.price|subtract:order_item.item.discount_price }}</td>
                </tr>

               {% endfor %}
```

This is how I'm able to send all the details to template. But I want to print all this details to the `views.py` console.

Comment: just print(order) in views.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `views.py` print `order` queryset

```
order = Order.objects.get(user=request.user, ordered=False)
print(order.quantity) #this will print quantity in the terminal
```

but if you had a queryset like

```
order = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
for order in orders:
    print(order.quantity)
```

in this case you would just loop through the queryset to print items in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to print data to console then you can just use `print(data)` and this will print the data to the console. If you want to print `context` then:

```
order = Order.objects.get(user=request.user, ordered=False)
context['object']=order
print(context)
return render(request,"Orderview.html",context)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is, to put these lines before rendering the template.

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
return context
```

Your code should look like this

```
order = Order.objects.get(user=request.user, ordered=False)
context['object']=order

import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
return context

return render(request,"Orderview.html",context)
```

When you refresh the page, it will hold/hang and you can run `print(context)`, `print(order)` or `print(context['object'])` statements in the console.